# How TreeSet checks for Duplicates

Tags: java, generics

I am checking how TreeSet checks for duplicate elements and have the following code

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class TreeDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new TreeDemo().go();
        }

    public void go()
    {
        Song s1 = new Song("song1","artist1");
        Song s2 = new Song("song2","artist2");
        Song s3 = new Song("song3","artist3");
        Song s4 = new Song("song3","artist3");

        Set<Song> tree = new TreeSet<Song>();

        tree.add(s1);
        tree.add(s2);
        tree.add(s3);
        tree.add(s4);

        System.out.println(tree);

    }
}

class Song implements Comparable<Song>{
    private String title;
    private String artist;

    public Song(String t, String a)
    {
        title=t;
        artist=a;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title; 
    }

    public int compareTo(Song s){
        //Song s = (Song)o;
        return title.compareTo(s.getTitle());
    }

public String toString(){
    return title;
}

}
```

When I execute this code, I get the following output

```
[song1, song2, song3]
```

My question is:-

- Even if I haven't implemented hashCode and equals method (I did implement the Comparable interface since its mandatory and needed to keep the Set sorted), how did TreeSet determine the duplicates?
- Did it use Object class default implementation? It looks like it used "title" field for this check since when I add  treats it as duplicate but when I add  it doesn't treats it as duplicate.

Thanks.

Comment: From the Comparable interface documentation, it says that "It is strongly recommended... that natural orderings be consistent with equals."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TreeSet` (or technically, the `TreeMap` that backs it) only uses the `compareTo()` function to compare the elements.
It does not use `Object`'s `.equals()` or `.hashCode()`. Moreover, if it had used any of them, your output would have been

```
[song1, song2, song3, song3]
```

because `Object`'s default implementation uses memory addresses to test object equality, not their members.

Comment: Yes, I realized it a bit later that TreeSet used only compareTo (implements Comparable) or compare (implements Comparator) for sorting and duplicate checks. It is Hashset that uses equals and hashCode.

Answer (score 2):

a comparator return < 0, 0 or > 0... So equals is implemented by compareTo returning 0. Thus

```
if (node1.compareTo(node2) == 0)
```

then the node is already in the set

Answer (score 1):

TreeSet implements a balanced binary search tree based upon ordering of its members (via the Comparable or Comparator interfaces), not on hashing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree